# Confused by this SVG path data

Tags: svg

The svg path for a file created in Inkscape is the following --

```
d="m 1.2499932,903.60456 0,146.50004 197.7500068,0 0,-146.50004 -197.7500068,0 z m 166.9375068,29.0625 0.75,88.62504 -3.53125,3.5312 -82.312507,0.25 -3.28125,-2.75 0.25,-82.09374 -12.625,0 -2.28125,5.8125 -43.9375,-0.25 c -4.90662,-3.46937 -0.70544,-8.07521 5.03125,-12.875 l 141.937507,-0.25 z"
```

I usually see an L, H, V, C, S, Q, T, or A command following the x,y position after the initial m command. In this case there are 5 x,y positions following the m command before the next command. This breaks my parsing code. I don't understand the role of the extra four positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All pairs of co-ordinates after the initial pair are [treated as implicit lineto commands](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands) i.e. as if they were preceded by an l (or an L if the inital command was an M).

Comment: I had a suspicion that was the case. Thank you.